# Passing value to EJS

Tags: express, ejs

I'm facing issue when passing a value from my express app.js file to ejs page.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index")
});


app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const value = req.body.value;

  function RoundTo(number, roundto){
    return roundto * Math.round(number/roundto);
  }

  const a = RoundTo(((((value / 10) + 2) + (value * 1.1)) * 1.05), .25);
  const b = RoundTo(((((value / 10) + 2.3) + (value * 1.4)) * 1.05), .25);
  const c = ((value * 1.12) + 0.5).toFixed(2);
  const d = ((value * 1.17) + 1).toFixed(2);
  const e = (((value * 1.15) * 1.05) + .7).toFixed(2);
  const f = RoundTo(((((value / 10) + 4) + (value * 1.1)) * 1.2), 0.25);
  const g = RoundTo(((((value / 10) + 4) + (value * 1.2)) * 1.5), 0.50);

  res.render("index", {
    rp4you: a,
    cp4you: b,
    b2b4youa: c,
    b2b4youb: d,
    valueptsb: e,
    rptsb: f,
    cptsb: g,
  });

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is Up and Running on Port 3000");
})
```

And here is my ejs file

```
  <body>
<form class="" action="/" method="post">
  <input type="number" step="any" name="value" value="">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<br>
<hr>
<br>
<p><%=rp4you%></p>
<p><%=cp4you%></p>
<p><%=b2b4youa%></p>
<p><%=b2b4youb%></p>
<p><%=costtsb%></p>
<p><%=rptsb%></p>
<p><%=cptsb%></p>

</body>
```

When I run the server. it given an error in ejs file.

> > 20|
> >
> > <%=rp4you%>

```
21| <table>

22|   <tr>

23|     <th>Label</th>
```

rp4you is not defined
at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), :12:25)
at index (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
at C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\app.js:15:7
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sherg\desktop\price_calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are making a `GET` request which is handled by this

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index")
});
```

and not this

```js
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const value = req.body.value;

  function RoundTo(number, roundto){
    return roundto * Math.round(number/roundto);
  }

  const a = RoundTo(((((value / 10) + 2) + (value * 1.1)) * 1.05), .25);
  const b = RoundTo(((((value / 10) + 2.3) + (value * 1.4)) * 1.05), .25);
  const c = ((value * 1.12) + 0.5).toFixed(2);
  const d = ((value * 1.17) + 1).toFixed(2);
  const e = (((value * 1.15) * 1.05) + .7).toFixed(2);
  const f = RoundTo(((((value / 10) + 4) + (value * 1.1)) * 1.2), 0.25);
  const g = RoundTo(((((value / 10) + 4) + (value * 1.2)) * 1.5), 0.50);

  res.render("index", {
    rp4you: a,
    cp4you: b,
    b2b4youa: c,
    b2b4youb: d,
    valueptsb: e,
    rptsb: f,
    cptsb: g,
  });

});
```

Which means it doesn't have access to any of the variables.

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify a little? I made the get request to render the route. and then post request to post variables.

Comment: @BuFahad Thats not how it works. Every `res.render` call needs a set of variables passed to it. When you make the get request, the request is handled by the first handler which simple calls `res.render` without passing any additional variables. When you make the post request, the second handler picks it up and calls `res.render` with the variables. They are not shared.